# How to set a cookie that is only valid for a specific domain like example.com but not its sub-domains?

Tags: cookies, dns, subdomain

if I have a domain `example.com`, is there any way to make cookies valid only for that specific domain and not for sub-domains like `www.example.com`?

I know I can set it to only `www.example.com`, but can it be without a sub-domain?

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are identified by the combination of their name, domain, and path. So if set correctly, you can limit it's scope to a specific domain/sub-domain and path.

Read Wiki's [HTTP Cookie's Attribute Section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie)
or [RFC2965](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2965)

Comment: However is there RFC2965 compliance across browsers?

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: I'm really not sure about that. Browsers `should` but then, who knows?

Answer (score -1):

Strictly speaking a cookie carrying the qualifier `";domain=example.com"` should not be visible to the "www.domain.com" domain.  Whereas `";domain=.example.com"` would be visible to the www host.

However I would be very wary of this.  I haven't tested this recently but I wouldn't be surprised to see some browsers not conforming properly to this.